# SQL Server index on group of columns doesn't perform well on individual column seek

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a non-clustered index on a group of columns as `(a, b, c, d)`, and I already use this index using a common query we have which search for those four columns in the where clause.

On the other side, when I try to search for column `(a)` by simply using:

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where a = value
```

here the performance is fine and execution plan shows it used my index.

But when I try to search for column `(d)` by simply using:

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where d = value
```

here the performance is bad, and execution plan already used same index but it shows hint that index is missing and impact is 98% and it suggest creating new index for the column (d).

Just for testing, I tried to create new index on this column and the performance become very good.

I don't want to stuck in redundant indices as the table is very huge (30GB) and it has about 100 million rows.

Any idea why my main index didn't perform well with all columns?

Column a data type is INT

Column d data type is TINYINT

SQL Server version is 2014 Enterprise.

Thanks.

Abed

Comment: If you have a list of people sorted by surname and then by given name, how readily can you use that list to count the number of people with the given name `Damien`? Indexes are only useful if your query filters on the leftmost `n` columns (`n` being between 1 and the number of columns in the index)

Comment: A **compound index** (made up from multiple columns) is **only** useful if you have the **n left-most columns** in your select; your index will work for a, (a,b), (a,b,c) or (a,b,c,d) but **IT CANNOT** ever help you with a query using **just** the (d) column. That's just the way compound indexes work

Answer (score 2):

If you have complex index on 4 columns (A,B,C,D )then you could use queries which filter:

```
1) WHERE A=...
2) WHERE A=... AND B =...
3) WHERE A=... AND B =... AND C=....
3) WHERE A=... AND B =... AND C=.... AND D=...
```

You CAN'T skip lead portion of the index, if you will filter like this :
`WHERE B= ... AND C= ... AND D=...` (thus, skipping A) performance will be BAD.

TRY creating separate indexes on each column, they are more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear how index on group of columns is working, but the reason why I use the index on group of columns and not using separate indices because I have another 5 columns included in the index and used as return values in the select clause, now I guess creating separate indices won't perform as the group index with include columns. Any suggestion here?

Comment: You could keep your complex index. (A,B,C,D). And beside of it create other 4 indexes on (A),(B),(C),(D).

Comment: Just remark that insert in the table, and update on these columns will take more time.

Comment: Also this will need much storage and more RAM space!